# Custom Tab bar in Android

Tags: tabbar, android, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

Is it possible to customize tab bar in android? Customize in the sense, like in iPhone, the tab bar is at the bottom of the screen; in Android, can we place the tab bar at the bottom and its content on top of it?

Comment: This will help you. http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/iphone-tabs-for-android-t14678.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes It is Possible to make custom Tab Bar in android like as in iphone you can get that from link . [visit here](http://android-vogue.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-make-custom-menu-bar-tabs-in.html)

Comment: This is not a recommended UI Design but this is the right answer to your question.

Comment: When i have answer this question i am new to work with TabView and in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's a late response but for saving future generation's neurons I'll put here easy to implement, working and 100% customizable solution.  As I initially came from iOS I was truly misled by the usage of the official bottom-navigation UI pattern from Android Architecture at the start of my project, but through pain and limitations I ended up with my own solution which was not that limited and much more flexible. Hope it'll help other developers: https://github.com/Codeveyor/Android-Tab-Bar