# How to make text in TabWidgets take two lines?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have text in a TabWidget that is currently longer than the length of the tabwidget, so android instead of making it two lines, it wraps it around and scrolls it.

How do I make the text in a TabWidget be two lines instead of just one?

Thanks

(I could make it into an image, but it seems like a hack)

Comment: you have to create custom tab View and set it . for more [help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911887/custom-tab-bar-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a `\n`  in your string and test it..